# Mouse.move values

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I understand that `Mouse.move` move the mouse from its current position, example:

`Mouse.move(100, 100);`

Will move the mouse to 100 pixels right and 100 pixels down.

But in reality it will move to somehting like 150 pixels right and/or 150 pixels down..

I already tested without cursor precision/acceleration and it doesn't change a thing.

What unit does the function use ?

I know about the 127 -127 limit, and i respect it, but still... when i ask to move 100,100 it doesn't move 100,100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mouse coordinates are not pixels. They are a proportion of the physical minimum/maximum parameters of the report descriptor. Since those aren't specified in the report descriptor they are taken to be the same as the logical: -127 to 127.

So moving 100 "units" is moving 100/(127-(-127)) of 100%, which is about 40%.

But 40% of what?

Well, 40% of an inch. Or what your OS believes that an inch is on your current screen.

In the HID specification:

> While Logical Minimum and Logical Maximum (extents) bound the values
>   returned by a device, Physical Minimum and Physical Maximum give
>   meaning to those bounds by allowing the report value to be offset and scaled.
>   For example, a thermometer might have logical extents of 0 and 999 but
>   physical extents of 32 and 212 degrees.The resolution can be determined
>   with the following algorithm:
>
> ```
> if ((Physical Maximum == UNDEFINED) || (Physical Minimum == UNDEFINED) || ((Physical Maximum == 0) && (Physical Minimum == 0))) {
>     Physical Maximum = Logical Maximum;
>     Physical Minimum = Logical Minimum;
> }
>
> If (Unit Exponent == UNDEFINED)
>     Unit Exponent = 0;
>
> Resolution = (Logical Maximum – Logical Minimum) / ((Physical Maximum – Physical Minimum) * (10^Unit Exponent))
> ```

Comment: it makes sense, thanks!